# the trouble of LineSeries-onMouseClick

Tags: lightningchart

My application scenario：
I Want to get the clicked point data and other attributes by clicking on the data point,
Then Get other data By PrimaryKey or other attributes.
Used to display on the other charts.
The Problem I am currently experiencing is:
The parameters returned by the "onMouseClick" event of the LineSeries,I cannot find the data of the clicked point and other attributes;
I tried two methods, but could not find the data of the clicked point.

[1]:

```
lineSeries.onMouseClick(function(serie, event) {
    let point = serie.solveNearestFromScreen({
        x: event.screenX,
        y: event.screenY
    });
    console.log(point)
})
```

[2]:

```
lineSeries.onMouseClick(function(serie, event) {
    console.log('serie', serie);
    console.log('event', event);
})
```

Hope to hear from you

Comment: Could you please specify the programming framework you are working in?

Comment: LightningChart JS

Answer (score 1):

To get the data points on mouse click you can register the onmouseclick event on series and call the solveNearestFromScreen method to get the data points. the parameters passed to the solveNearestFromScreen should be location of the mouse cursor location translated into engine location for example you could refer the code below:-

```
//attaching an on click event to the seires
 series.onMouseClick( ( series, event ) => {
     //convert client location to engine canvas location
        const engineLocation = chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine( event.clientX, event.clientY )
        
        //fetching the data point and other parameters. The location parameter gives the data point
        console.log( series.solveNearestFromScreen( chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine( event.clientX, event.clientY ) ) )

    } )
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Ansower,Very helpful to me